# Add gradient color scale on a kable column

Tags: r, colors, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I need to create a table in the kable whose cells in a specific column have different colors based on the cell value, such as Excel's conditional color scale, but I'm not sure how to do that. Specifically, I need to turn the extreme positive values into green, the extreme negative values into red, and the values close to 0 into white like the following impression taken from Excel.

[image]

Anyone here can enlighten me?

Comment: you can take a look at the [`kableExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Column_spec) package

Comment: A reproducible example and the type of document you are producing with `knitr` (HTML/PDF/Word) would be helpful to answer your question.